# how to call to this map function

Tags: scheme

I saw a code on a book about how to create a map function in Scheme, the code is the following:

```
(define map (lambda (f L)
              (if null? L '()
                  (cons (f (car L)) (map f (cdr L))))))

(define square (lambda (x)
    (* x x)))        

(define square-list (lambda (L)
                      (map square L)))
```

Supposedly I can call it with:

```
(map square-list '(1 2 3 4))
```

but it is throwing me the following error:

```
SchemeError: too many operands in form: (null? L (quote ()) (cons (f (car L)) (map f (cdr L))))

Current Eval Stack:
-------------------------
0:  (map square-list (quote (1 2 3 4)))
```

How should I call this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors. First, you forgot to surround the `null?` check with parentheses (and notice a better way to indent your code):

```
(define map
  (lambda (f L)
    (if (null? L)
        '()
        (cons (f (car L))
              (map f (cdr L))))))
```

Second, you're expected to call the procedure like this:

```
(square-list '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 4 9 16 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parens around `null? L`, i.e. your condition should probably look like

```
(if (null? L) '()
    (cons ...))
```